# Ruby on Rails: how to pass an instance variable from a controller to another controller via a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and web development, so please bear with me.
I have been trying to build an automated deployment system of sorts for a site.  I have a form in my home page which gets a name field for a site_name model, and I am trying to pass this name (and also site_name instance) to another controller which makes the deployment. However, I couldn't manage to pass the name correctly. How can I pass an instance variable from a from to another controller?

These are the files I use FYI

home.html.erb

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <div class="input-group">
    <%= form_for @site_name, url: {action: "instantiate", controller: "script_execute"}, html: {method: "get"} do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", instantiate_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

script_execute_controller.rb (which contains instantiate action)

```
class ScriptExecuteController < ApplicationController

  def instantiate
    site_name = @site_name.name
    @hostname = 'myhostname'
    @username = 'myusername'
    @password = 'mypassword'
    @cmd = "yes #{site_name} | ./denemescr.sh"
    begin
      ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
      res = ssh.exec!(@cmd)
      ssh.close
      puts res
    end
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb (controller for the home page)

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @site_name = SiteName.new
  end
end
```

Comment: The linkage is really just the http form parameters. You have to format the form id and name in such a way that they get picked up by the controller correctly. Try looking at your log file and see what params are being passed in...that will show you what names they are using.

Comment: I can see that the form gets the parameter correctly and it also updates the instance variable correctly. However, the instantiate action in the controller can't get access to that name somehow. POST action is correctly done with the name, but the name can't be used and the @site_name instance the controller tries to use is nil, which suggests that it was never updated/initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you are using a GET to post a form? Change it to a post and grab the name via params[:name] in the action the post is being routed to. You instantiate the instance variable initially and you are actually posting to your method instantiate.

Comment: As I said I am new to the web development, I actually don't know the real difference/distinction between GET/POST etc. and when to/ not to use them. The form also tried to use POST and I've added a post action to routes.rb for that. I'll try what you have suggested. Thanks!